# Show that $(n-j)! \leq \frac{n!}{(j+1)!}$

Tags: inequality, factorial

I have to show that $$(n-j)! \leq \frac{n!}{(j+1)!}$$

I tried to develop $(n-j!)$ as $\frac{n!}{n(n-1)\cdot\cdot\cdot(n-j+1)}$ but I have no clue after that because I end up with $$\frac{1}{n(n-1)\cdot\cdot\cdot(n-j+1)} \leq \frac{1}{(j+1)!}$$

$${n(n-1)\cdot\cdot\cdot(n-j+1)} \geq {(j+1)!}$$

Comment: It's not true for $j=n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also just induct on $n$. The base case for $n = j+1$ is easy. The induction step isn't difficult either, as
$$ (n+1-j)! = (n+1-j) (n-j)! \leq (n+1-j) \frac{n!}{(j+1)!} \leq (n+1) \frac{n!}{(j+1)!} = \frac{(n+1)!}{(j+1)!}. $$

Answer (score 2):

If $j\geq 0$ and $j<n$ then $n+1 \leq {n+1\choose j+1}$, thus

$$1\leq {1\over n+1}{n+1\choose j+1} = {n! \over (j+1)!(n-j)!}$$

Comment: It might also be useful to not that $n+1=\binom{n+1}{1}$, to make the first inequality more obvious.

Comment: why $\binom{n+1}{1} \leq \binom{n+1}{j+1}$

Comment: Well it is kind of empirical fact, take a look at a Pascal triangle.

Comment: Let $F$ be a family of all $j$ element subset of set $M=\{1,2,....,n\}$. For each element in $F$ let $m$ be minimum and $M$ maximum of this element. Now we have a surjective map $f:F\to M$ which takes $X$ to $m$ if $m<j$ and other vise to M. Thus $|M|\geq |F|$.

Comment: but $\binom{n+1}{1} \geq \binom{n+1}{2}$ so ..

Comment: That is not true.

Comment: but if n=1 it's true

Comment: That's why must be $j<n$ ?

Comment: We have $j \leq n$ to have a well-defined $(n-j)!$. Now $j<n$, else obviously the inequality is wrong.  And hence if $n = 1$, then $j = 0$, so the inequality $n+1 \leq \binom{n+1}{j+1}$ remains correct for $n=1$.